# Mac OS X sound output

Tags: c++, c, macos, audio, buffer

Are there any examples for how to output a raw sound buffer on Mac OS X?
Something like `pa_simple_write()` for pulseaudio or `waveOutWrite()` from WINAPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an [AudioQueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioQueueReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005117).

Next you need to [allocate a buffer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioQueueReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005117).  Once allocated, you then fill it with data and [enqueue it](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioQueueReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005117).  Finally you call [AudioQueueStart](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioQueueReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005117).  You can then immediately call [AudioQueueStop](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioQueueReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005117) passing false as the last parameter.

The above won't work very well, though, if you need to play multiple sounds simultaneously.  If you wish to do that, AFAIK, you'll need a more complex setup where you mix audio into a buffer.  That will get complicated quickly, though ...

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I've run into is to use [libao](http://www.xiph.org/ao/). Conveniently, it's also cross-platform.

Comment: good notice, but i've already made realization for windows and linux without libraries such as SDL or libao, only mac os left with it's CoreAudio or something like...

Comment: rtaudio and portaudio are similar cross-platform alternatives. Probably easier to work with than CoreAudio directly (and PortAudi ships with great sample code), but CoreAudio isn't bad.